# PL/SQL on SquirreL SQL Client 3.7.1

Tags: oracle, plsql, squirrel-sql

I was trying to execute PL/SQL scripts on SQuirrel but it doesn't seem to work.

I configured Oracle Thin Driver by adding ojdbc7.jar on "Extra Class Path", was able to connect to the database but when tried to run a simple code it gives an error:

```
-- code
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello World');
END;
/

-- error
Error: ORA-06550: line 2, column 37:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( % ;

SQLState:  65000
ErrorCode: 6550
Error occurred in:
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello World')
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Squirrel probably doesn't support anonymous PL/SQL blocks, or uses a different delimiter for that.

Comment: Try removing the `/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement worked for me (the `/` is necessary for SQuirrel SQL Client):

```
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Hello World');
END;
/
```

**However**, you won't see the output in the usual Results tab.  You need to open the Oracle Database Output window.  As far as I can see you can only open it with a button on the toolbar.  You'll also need to enable auto refresh or manually refresh the output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello World');
END;
```

by removing `/`

Comment: Still no good:

`Error: ORA-06550: line 2, column 37:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( % ;

SQLState:  65000
ErrorCode: 6550
Error occurred in:
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello World')`

Answer (score 0):

When installing the SQuirreL, try including the Oracle Plugin.  This works for me in version 3.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle plugin for Squirrel is needed for executing queries in BEGIN - END;
Had the same problem untill reinstalled squirrel with Oracle plugin.