# PL/SQL on SquirreL SQL Client 3.8.1

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, squirrel-sql

I am trying to execute a PL/SQL anonymous block with SQuirrel SQL:

```
BEGIN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

However, I get this error:

```
Error: ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ;

SQLState:  65000
ErrorCode: 6550
Error occurred in:
begin
    NULL
```

I am using an Oracle 11g Express DB with the Oracle Thin Driver.

The reason for wanting to execute a PL/SQL block is so that I can create a table, and catch the exception caused if it already exists.

I have looked into similar questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/43265502 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42287207 and others, but still cannot get SQuirrel to be happy with anonymous PL/SQL blocks. From what these other questions seem to say, it should be possible to use these blocks.

Why will this script not compile?

Comment: Maybe it isn't expecting the `/`? I don't have SQuirreL though so that's a bit of a guess.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference to the error message if the slash is removed, unfortunately.